# C# code in the View, Cloudinary API guide

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cloudinary

I am trying to make an asp.net mvc 5 app by this [ASP.NET image upload](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/dotnet_image_upload#direct_uploading_environment_setup) guide.

I am curious about this part of the guide ([on the photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1kpw.png)):
as I understand at that part I am supposed to write the code in my View (cshtml) page. (Cause before there was attaching js's and running scripts in "<"script">" tag)

How can I write such C# code in the View? Where am I wrong?

```
string cors_location = (new UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri) { Path = Url.Content("~/Content/cloudinary_cors.html") }).ToString();
```

Comment: if this info necessary: it should be non-server app that works client-side, but my server should get a link of uploaded file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# code in a view generally belongs in a server side block like this ...

```
@{

string cors_location = (new UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    { Path = Url.Content("~/Content/cloudinary_cors.html") }).ToString();


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I write such C# code in the View? Where am I wrong?

Hi.
like this by adding the '@'sign

```
@{string cors_location = (new UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri) { Path = Url.Content("~/Content/cloudinary_cors.html") }).ToString();}
```

also please check http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c

> my server should get a link of uploaded file

To manage this You should do something like this:

create property in Your model class for eg.

```
public string ImgUrl {get;set;}
```

In Your View controller you should pass url value from view

```
Img.Url = "My Image Url passed from View";
```

and then save Your model to Db.

For more please check http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/259/asp-net-mvc-5-with-ef-6-working-with-files

Comment: Yep, I know how to do all the rest, I've just wanted to describe my problem more completely. Nevertheless, thank you for all given material and your respond, I'll defntly read this articles later. 
P.S. want to give you rep, but my rep is below 15 yet so I can't.

Comment: Also, can I feel free to make any kind of discussion like above in comments block, or stackoverflow forbids it?
I am new to stackoverflow, so I don't know about any decensies here.

Comment: Yes. feel free to discuss here.